# Vectorised of loop with condition code using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, loops, conditional-statements, vectorization

I am trying to convert simple code into a vectorizer. I am new to the concept.

I've tried by using the `np.vectorize` option, but it throws an error:

Can you please help me to solve the problem? Is there any other better way to vectorize it?

---

Code:

```
   def test(s,m):
      mean_matrix=s
      m2=s/m // forming an array
      result=[]
      for x in m2:
         return x/5



  s=np.random.random(50)
  m=np.random.random(100)
  temp=np.vectorize(test,otypes=[np.float],cache=False)
  out = temp(s,m)
```

Comment: The principle of numpy.vectorize is to enable applying a function over successive tuples of the input arrays. For instance, if you have a function that takes only scalars as inputs, you'll be able to apply it to vectors. In your case, you don't want to use this function because the `test` function is already a vectorized function as it accepts vectors.

Comment: It would have been a good idea to use numpy.vectorize if you had a function `test` such that `result[i]=test(s[i],m[i])`. This is not the configuration here because `test` requires the whole `s` vector to compute mean for instance.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not do the speed enhancing 'vectorizing' that you seek.  Your use of `otypes` tells me you read its docs, but evidently you missed the performance disclaimer.

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalar arguments to your function, hence the complaint when you try `s[0]`.   `otypes` determines the return dtype, but does nothing about the inputs.  When developing code like this, it's a good idea to check the type/shape/dtype of the input argument.

Answer (score 1):

First split your code into the part used in a loop (which is possible to vectorize) and the rest (which is already vectorized):

```
def kernel(s, x):
    i = 0
    initial_value = s[0].copy()
    while initial_value < x:
        i = i+1
        initial_value += s[i]
    return i

def test_split(s, m):
    mean_matrix = s.mean() # 5 usec
    product_m2 = mean_matrix * m # forming an array, 2 usec
    return [kernel(s, x) for x in product_m2] # 167 usec
```

`test_split` does the same thing as `test`, it's just refactored.  I've annotated each line to say how much time is spent there, to show that speeding up the loop will make a difference.

If you use `np.vectorize()` it looks like this:

```
def test_vectorize(s, m):
    mean_matrix = s.mean() # 5 usec
    product_m2 = mean_matrix * m # forming an array, 2 usec
    kernel_vec = np.vectorize(lambda x: kernel(s, x)) # 2 usec
    return kernel_vec(product_m2) # 194 usec
```

This is slower!  That's because `np.vectorize()` does not make things faster, it only changes the aesthetics.  It still uses a Python loop internally.  Better to forget it exists.

So we need a different approach, and for that we need to think about what `kernel` does.  And it seems to me that what it does is find the longest initial subsequence of `s` whose sum is less than `x`.  [`s.cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) will give us the running total that we need, but how do we search for its maximal length that is less than each `x` in `product_m2`?  We can't use a loop or it will be slow again.  But we can use [`np.searchsorted()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).  Here it is:

```
def test_fast(s, m):
     mean_matrix = s.mean() # 5 usec
     product_m2 = mean_matrix * m # forming an array, 2 usec
     s_sum = s.cumsum() # 1 usec
     return s_sum.searchsorted(product_m2) # 2 usec
```

And like that we have a 14x speedup.

Comment: Thanks, John, for your answer. I understand your point. but your code only returns only one value. but as per my initial code, it should return m length vector where each value from product_m2 should compare the initial value of s[0] then find the longest initial subsequence of s whose sum is less than product_m2 and then return the highest value of loop.  This process repeat with all M values and so we can get m vector.  May you please guide.

Comment: @Chanakya: Did you try running my code?  If I use your example `s` (length 50) and `m` (length 100) and run `test_fast(s, m)`, it returns an array of 100 elements having the same values as the list of 100 elements returned by your original `test(s, m)`.

Comment: Zwick thanks for your reply. I tried your code and calling it as                                          
` m=np.random.random(100) `                                                                          
              s = np.random.random(10)                                                                                       test_fast(s, m)   ` but it only return one value

Comment: And what was the output?  It should output an array.  It does on my computer.  Show the output you get, and tell us what version of NumPy you're using.

Comment: Thanks, John. it's working, Actually it was taking the working value...Your help is much appreciated. May you please tell me the effective way to learn vectorizer.